# Hive problem MetaException(message:Error creating transactional connection factory)

Tags: mysql, hive

i'm setting up a cluster with Hadoop version 3.1.1 and hive version 3.1.1. After setup hive-site.xml and Mysql and its connector.

when i run hive --service metastore i got the following error. Any idea how to solve it?

Hadoop version 3.1.1

Hive version 3.1.1

Hive is setup in remote Mode.

Using Ununtu 16.04 LTS

Mysql-connector is already in /hive/lib

2018-11-29 21:58:54: Starting Hive Metastore Server

```
MetaException(message:Error creating transactional connection factory)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:8926)
    at `enter code here`org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:8843)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:232)
Caused by: MetaException(message:Error creating transactional connection factory)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:80)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:671)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:830)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:334)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initializeHelper(ObjectStore.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStoreForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:718)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:696)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:690)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:538)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor75.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:330)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:203)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.<init>(AbstractStoreManager.java:162)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:285)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor74.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContextHelper.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContextHelper.java:133)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.initialise(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:422)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:817)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.isValid(I)Z
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkDriverSupport(PoolBase.java:432)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:403)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:361)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:199)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:444)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:515)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:112)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:72)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.HikariCPConnectionPoolFactory.createConnectionPool(HikariCPConnectionPoolFactory.java:176)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:117)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<init>(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:82)
    ... 59 more
Exception in thread "main" MetaException(message:Error creating transactional connection factory)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:8926)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:8843)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:232)
Caused by: MetaException(message:Error creating transactional connection factory)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:80)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:671)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:830)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:334)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initializeHelper(ObjectStore.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStoreForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:718)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:696)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:690)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:773)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:538)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor75.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:330)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:203)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.<init>(AbstractStoreManager.java:162)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:285)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor74.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContextHelper.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContextHelper.java:133)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.initialise(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:422)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:817)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.isValid(I)Z
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkDriverSupport(PoolBase.java:432)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:403)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:361)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:199)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:444)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:515)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:112)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:72)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.HikariCPConnectionPoolFactory.createConnectionPool(HikariCPConnectionPoolFactory.java:176)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:117)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<init>(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:82)
    ... 59 more
```