# Unable to initiate metastore in Hive with Hodoop

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, hive

I have *Hadoop 3.3.2*, *Hive 3.1.3*, *MySql 8.0.29*(apt install mysql-server) installed. *MySql* is running properly with `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u debian-sys-maint -p` command. But unable to run any command in *Hive*. I'm getting `FAILED: HiveException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient` exception.

Then in SO, I found [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42343420/12357035), which says to execute `hive --service metastore`. But, when I execute this command, I get this error:

```
2022-07-24 17:15:57: Starting Hive Metastore Server
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hdoop/apache-hive-3.1.3-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hdoop/hadoop-3.3.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
MetaException(message:Error creating transactional connection factory)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8672)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8667)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:8937)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:8854)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
Caused by: MetaException(message:Error creating transactional connection factory)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:208)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:80)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:671)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:830)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:334)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:213)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:651)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:694)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initializeHelper(ObjectStore.java:484)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:376)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStoreForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:720)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:698)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:692)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:775)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:540)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor76.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:330)
        at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:203)
        at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.<init>(AbstractStoreManager.java:162)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:285)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor75.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContextHelper.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContextHelper.java:133)
        at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.initialise(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:422)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:817)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Attempt to invoke the "HikariCP" plugin to create a ConnectionPool gave an error : Failed to initialize pool: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:232)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:117)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<init>(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:82)
        ... 59 more
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:544)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:536)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:112)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:72)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.HikariCPConnectionPoolFactory.createConnectionPool(HikariCPConnectionPoolFactory.java:176)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
        ... 61 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor81.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3996)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1284)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2137)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor78.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:356)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:199)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:444)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:515)
        ... 65 more
Exception in thread "main" MetaException(message:Error creating transactional connection factory)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8672)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8667)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:8937)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:8854)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
Caused by: MetaException(message:Error creating transactional connection factory)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:208)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:80)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory
NestedThrowables:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:671)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:830)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:334)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:213)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:651)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:694)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initializeHelper(ObjectStore.java:484)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:376)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStoreForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:720)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:698)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:692)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:775)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:540)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor76.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:330)
        at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:203)
        at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.<init>(AbstractStoreManager.java:162)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:285)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor75.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:606)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContextHelper.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContextHelper.java:133)
        at org.datanucleus.PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.initialise(PersistenceNucleusContextImpl.java:422)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:817)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Attempt to invoke the "HikariCP" plugin to create a ConnectionPool gave an error : Failed to initialize pool: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:232)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:117)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<init>(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:82)
        ... 59 more
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:544)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:536)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:112)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:72)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.HikariCPConnectionPoolFactory.createConnectionPool(HikariCPConnectionPoolFactory.java:176)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
        ... 61 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor81.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3996)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1284)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2137)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor78.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:356)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:199)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:444)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:515)
        ... 65 more
```

I am unable to resolve this error. *$HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml* looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/hive_metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>


<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hiveuser</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>hivepassword</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>datanucleus.autoCreateTables</name>
 <value>True</value>
 </property>

</configuration>
```

I also have *mysql-connector-java-5.1.9.jar* in *$HIVE_HOME/lib*. I am not getting what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53548401/12357035). But it has no answers!!

Comment: Since you are using mysql 8, have you tried 1. adding the mysql-connector for java 8, [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) 2. changing the driver name in `hive-site.xml` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: @ggordon Now I downloaded  `mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar` from  [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.29). Also, changed driver name in `hive-site.xml`. But still exact same error persists.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu-20.04 inside WSL Windows-11.

Comment: Does the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50131831/4307136) to enable native passwords/auth protocols help?

Comment: @ggordon Thanks for your suggestions, I was able to track down the mistake. I have posted it in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to suggestions by @ggordon in comments under the question. I followed the steps in [this website](https://hadooptutorials.info/2021/11/26/configure-apache-hive-metastore-using-mysql-database/) with some small modifications.

1. When I executed `mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p`, I was getting `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)` error. So, I changed it to use loopback address: `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u debian-sys-maint -p`.
2. `CREATE USER 'hiveuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'hivepassword'` has to be changed to `CREATE USER 'hiveuser'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'hivepassword'`, since that is what we are using. (I missed this step in question)
3. `GRANT all on . to hiveuser` was not working for me. So, after some googling, I changed it to `GRANT all on hive_metastore.* to 'hiveuser'@'127.0.0.1'`.
4. `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL` property in *$HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml* was set to `jdbc:mysql://localhost/hive_metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`. It has to be changed to `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/hive_metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`.

With these changes, I followed steps in the above linked site, and it is working fine now.